# How to create a new transparent bitmap?

Tags: java, image-processing, bitmap

I need to create a `bitmap` with a determined **width** and a **height**, but transparent.

How can achieve it?

I can't find the way on goole or stackoverflow :S

Thanks

Comment: a bitmap, or any image ?

Comment: The most common bitmap formats don't support transparency. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to create? (Starting with: A file? An in-memory object?)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

TYPE_INT_ARGB - Represents an image with 8-bit RGBA color components with the colors Blue, Green, and Red stored in 3 bytes and 1 byte of alpha. (Alpha means transparency)

You can easily read and write several formats from files. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  // log
}
```

Transparency is not supported for all formats only PNG and GIF do support transparency (afaik).